# How to change fragment action bar title color in bottomnaviagtionview

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-actionbar, bottomnavigationview

following is the navigation xml I wish there could be option as labelcolor any other solution to change label color as label appears on action bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/app_navigation.xml"

    app:startDestination="@id/Fragment1"
    >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/Fragment1"
       
        android:label="Fragment1"

        tools:layout="@layout/fragment1" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/Fragment2"
        
        android:label="Fragment2"

        tools:layout="@layout/fragment2" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/Fragment3"
        
        android:label="Fragment3"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment3" />
   
</navigation>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
       android:id="@+id/toolbarNav"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
       android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
       android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
       android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" >
```

add `app:titleTextColor="@color/white"` in toolbar. It'll work.